# Java Recursion: is saving a variable and then passing to method slower than passing directly

Tags: java, recursion, complexity-theory

I'm writing a recursive Java algorithm and I'm trying to make it work as fast as possible.

Now I'm facing a dilema since I would like to store some values into variables and would then like to pass the variable to the next recursive call (instead of passing the values directly). This approach would save be a few if statements. However, I'm wondering whether it would also make the program slower because it has to store a variable on every single call.

So I'm wondering whether this simplified problem:

```
public int Sum(int a) {
    if (a==0)
        return 0;

    int tmp = heavyComputation(a);
    return (tmp + Sum(a-1))
```

is any slower than this:

```
public int Sum(int a) {
    if (a==0)
        return 0;

    return (heavyComputation(a) + Sum(a-1))
```

in this simplified example it doesn't really make much difference but in my code, the first approach would save me quite a few ugly if statements.

Thanks!

Comment: This is considered micro-optimization, and should be avoided. The difference in performance is un-noticable. If the identifier for the variable was more descriptive, I'd say go for the variable to increase readability

Comment: `heavyComptation()` will be performed once and its result will be used as argument for next recursive `sum()` call. Overhead will be unnoticeable.

Comment: I have have confused you all with the heavyComputation() which really isn't relevant here. What I'd like to know is whether the sace complexity will be increased with the first approach.